Laravel Jetstream: Does not update custom additional profile information
I customized the app\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserProfileInformation.php file with new fields.
There is a ZIP code search performed with JQuery, but when there is a change of address, the new data is not updated. Below is a screenshot of the dump.
View Code


<div class="flex col-span-6 sm:col-span-4 justify-items-center">
    <div class="w-1/4">
        <x-label for="zipcode" value="{{ __('CEP') }}" />
        <x-input x-mask="99999-999" id="zipcode" type="text" name="zipcode" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model="state.zipcode"/>
        <x-input-error for="zipcode" class="mt-2" />
    </div>
    <div class="w-2/4 ml-5">
        <x-label for="street" value="{{ __('Logradouro') }}" />
        <x-input id="street" type="text" name="street" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model="state.street"/>
        <x-input-error for="street" class="mt-2" />
    </div>
    <div class="w-1/4 ml-5">
        <x-label for="number" value="{{ __('Num.') }}" />
        <x-input id="number" type="text" name="number" name="number" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model="state.number"/>
        <x-input-error for="number" class="mt-2" />
    </div>
</div>



UpdateUserProfileInformation.php


if ($input['email'] !== $user->email &&
    $user instanceof MustVerifyEmail) {
    $this->updateVerifiedUser($user, $input);
} else {
    $user->forceFill([
        'name' => $input['name'],
        'email' => $input['email'],
        'cell_phone' => $input['cell_phone'],
        'blood_type' => $input['blood_type'],
        'contact_name' => $input['contact_name'],
        'contact_phone' => $input['contact_phone'],
        'birth_date' => $input['birth_date'],
        'shirt_size' => $input['shirt_size'],
        'shirt_sleeve' => $input['shirt_sleeve'],
        'shirt_name' => $input['shirt_name'],
        'street' => $input['street'],
        'number' => $input['number'],
        'complement' => $input['complement'],
        'neighborhood' => $input['neighborhood'],
        'city' => $input['city'],
        'state' => $input['state'],
        'zipcode' => $input['zipcode'],
    ])->save();
}






